# PHP: Account creation AFTER e-mail verification

Tags: email-verification

I'm building a website with a login and registration system where the users' information will be stored on a database. I'm implementing a standard e-mail verification step after the account creation. The process is the following: An account is created, but has a 'verified' flag set to False. Then, an e-mail is sent to the user with a link to verify the account. Finally, after the user clicks the link, the 'verified' flag is set to True.

This should be sufficient, but it got me thinking. What happens to the unverified accounts? Someone could set up millions of unverified accounts that fill up my database storage space and available usernames. This could be problematic.

Is there a way to build a similar system in which the account would only be stored in the database AFTER the verification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve your "Problem" would be to use a Capchta at the registration and/or to delete all not-activated accounts when the registration date is further ago than x days.

Comment: A Captcha would be a nice idea. As for the second suggestion, x days may already be enough to clog the database.

Answer (score -1):

You could encrypt all information of the registration in the verification link, instead of storing that information in a new user account.

When the user clicks the registration link, you would decrypt that information and create the account.

To keep the verification URL as short as possible, this would require to minimize the amount of information you request during registration. I would suggest to ask for the E-Mail only and to request all the other attributes on the verification page.